# limit as n approaches infinity for reduction formula of sin integral

Tags: integration, limits

I have found a reduction formula for sin^n(x) (between 0 and pi/2, n even) by integration by parts. It is, in its general form:
[image]

I want to know what this tends to as n-> infinity. If I think of the sin graph between 0 and pi/2, it is a positive area and so summing the area element of this graph surely will make it diverge to infinity? How can I show this from the reduction formula I made? Maybe use L'Hop or a Taylor expansion?

Comment: **oh sorry yes that is an assumption made you are right because you reach I(0) which obviously evaluates to pi/2. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2k-1}{2k}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)=\exp\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)$$

$$-\infty<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)<-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2k}=-\infty$$

$$\implies\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2k-1}{2k}=\exp(-\infty)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

*Because of your user name !*

Using the gamma function, $$I_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }} 2 \frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$$ Using Stirling approximation, we then have $$\log(I_n)=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right)-\frac{1}{4 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ making then $$\color{red}{I_n\approx\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2n}} e^{-\frac{1}{4 n}}}$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

For illustration purposes, the following table gives, for $n$, the exact value of $I_n$, its decimal representation, and the numerical value of the above approximation
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 1.000000 & 0.976082 \\
 3 & \frac{2}{3} & 0.666667 & 0.665745 \\
 5 & \frac{8}{15} & 0.533333 & 0.533163 \\
 7 & \frac{16}{35} & 0.457143 & 0.457089 \\
 9 & \frac{128}{315} & 0.406349 & 0.406326 \\
 11 & \frac{256}{693} & 0.369408 & 0.369397 \\
 13 & \frac{1024}{3003} & 0.340992 & 0.340986 \\
 15 & \frac{2048}{6435} & 0.31826 & 0.318256 \\
 17 & \frac{32768}{109395} & 0.299538 & 0.299536 \\
 19 & \frac{65536}{230945} & 0.283773 & 0.283771
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k = 1}^{N}{2k - 1 \over 2k} & =
\prod_{k = 1}^{N}{k - 1/2 \over k} = {\pars{1/2}^{\overline{N}} \over N!} =
{1 \over N!}\,{\Gamma\pars{1/2 + N} \over \Gamma\pars{1/2}} =
{1 \over \root{\pi}}\,{\pars{N - 1/2}! \over N!}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&
{1 \over \root{\pi}}\,{\root{2\pi}\pars{N - 1/2}^{N}\expo{-\pars{N - 1/2}} \over
\root{2\pi}N^{N + 1/2}\expo{-N}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{1 \over \root{\pi}}\,{1 \over N^{1/2}}\,\
\overbrace{\pars{1 - {1/2 \over N}}^{N}\expo{1/2}}
^{\ds{\to\ 1\ \mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}}
\\[5mm]
\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,& \bbx{\large 0}
\end{align}